# Capture Slow Output from Method

Tags: c#

I have a slow running utility method that logs one line of output at a time. I need to be able to output each of those lines and then read them from other locations in code. I have attempted using Tasks and Streams similar to the code below:

```
public static Task SlowOutput(Stream output)
{
    Task result = new Task(() =>
    {
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(output))
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then called like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
var t = SlowOutput(ms);
using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    while (!t.IsCompleted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
    }
}
```

But of course, `sr.ReadLine()` is always empty because as soon as the method's `sw.WriteLine()` is called, it changes the position of the underlying stream to the end.

What I'm trying to do is pipe the output of the stream by maybe queueing up the characters that the method outputs and then consuming them from outside the method.  Streams don't seem to be the way to go.

Is there a generally accepted way to do this?

Comment: does it have to be a stream. I would use a blockingqueue

Comment: No, it does not have to be a stream. *Googles blockingqueue*

Comment: What's driving this, i.e., what's the requirement here?  Are you just experimenting with streams?

Comment: `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>` is the full name, [here is a overview of it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview)

Comment: I'm not experimenting with streams, just trying to understand a concept.  How do I pipe an output from a method?

Comment: Just a FYI you should almost never use `new Task(` unless you are writing a custom task scheduler use `Task.Run(` instead.

Comment: sry yes blockingcollection not blockingqueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is switch to a [`BlockingCollection<String>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7).

```
public static Task SlowOutput(BlockingCollection<string> output)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            output.Add(i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        output.Complete​Adding();
    }
}
```

consumed by

```
var bc = BlockingCollection<string>();
SlowOutput(bc);
foreach(var line in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable()) //Blocks till a item is added to the collection. Leaves the foreach loop after CompleteAdding() is called and there are no more items to be processed.
{
    Console.WriteLine(line)
}
```